# How to extract exact matches with list from one dataframe column to another one?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with text that I want to use to find matches from a list of words (around 1k words in there).

I have managed to get the absence/presence of the word from the list in the dataframe, but it is also important to me to know which word matched.
Sometimes there is exact match with more than one word from the list, I would like to have them all.

I tried to use the code below, but it gives me partial matches - syllables instead of full words.

```
#this is an example of what I want

import pandas as pd

df_data= [['orange','0','0'],
  ['apple and lemon','1','apple, lemon'],
  ['lemon and orange','1', 'lemon'],
 ]

df= pd.DataFrame(df_data,columns=['text','match','exact word(s)'])

#this is the list of words I need to match
exactmatch = ['apple', 'lemon']

#this is what I've tried, for some rows it gives me words I want, and for some it gives me parts of the word

pattern1 = '|'.join(exactmatch)
df['contains'] = df['text'].str.extract("(" + "|".join(exactmatch) +")", expand=False)
```

Unlike similar questions, here I'm interested in using patterns from a list, and not just one regex.

The question was marked as duplicate, however, the solution from the linked post does not work:

```
df['contains'] = df['text'].str.extractall
("(" + "|".join(exactmatch) +")").unstack().apply(','.join, 1)
```

This is what I get:

```
TypeError: ('sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index 2')
```

Answer (score 0):

An [`applymap(str)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) was missing so that `",".join` could work properly for this case.

```
import pandas as pd

df_data= [['orange','0','0'],
  ['apple and lemon','1','apple, lemon'],
  ['lemon and orange','1', 'lemon'],
 ]

df= pd.DataFrame(df_data,columns=['text','match','exact word(s)'])

exactmatch = ['apple', 'lemon']

df_tmp = df['text'].str.extractall("(" + "|".join(exactmatch) + ")")
df_tmp = df_tmp.unstack().fillna("").applymap(str).apply(",".join, 1)

# fix when empty column is used with join
df["Word(s)"] = df_tmp.replace(",$","", regex=True)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

```
               text match exact word(s)      Word(s)
0            orange     0             0            0
1   apple and lemon     1  apple, lemon  apple,lemon
2  lemon and orange     1         lemon        lemon
```